# How to have an offline copy of server?

Tags: ftp, synchronization

Basically, what I want is something like Dropbox, but it is for my whole server.

If I place a folder into it, it updates on my server, and is accessible through my URL.

If I delete something, it removes it from the server too.

It also seconds as a offline backup of everything on my server.

Is there any app like that?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: it sounds like you want an FTP client, but with a local cache. I would discourage this as a form of backup, though it may have other uses. What are the specific scenarios which you'd like to have a better solution for?

Comment: @WillPalmer, why would you discourage it? I basically want the ease of using Dropbox with FTP. It's a big PITA to use a FTP client.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Most (OSX, Windows, Ubuntu) these days have FTP support integrated into the filesystem browser

Comment: I'm fairly certain the Windows XP has native FTP support. Have you tried enabling the address bar in the file explorer, then typing `ftp://example.com/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTPBox](http://ftpbox.org/) seems to do what you want.